# Configuration depending on launch mode

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.4

Play can be launched in dev mode (via `run`), in production mode (via `start`) or in test mode. Is there a way to provide a different config file (`conf/application.conf`) depending on which mode it is launched in?

Comment: What `Playframework` version do you use?

Comment: @MonCalamari 2.4 atm, will upgrade to 3.0 sometime.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I usually have a base configuration (`application.conf`) and three extra configs per environment. In `Play Framework 2.4` it can be done by extending [GuiceApplicationLoader](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection) and merging base conf with your environment specific conf. You can go one step forward and provide different guice modules per environment.

Scala version:

```
class CustomApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader {

    override protected def builder(context: Context): GuiceApplicationBuilder = {
        val builder = initialBuilder.in(context.environment).overrides(overrides(context): _*)
        context.environment.mode match {
            case Prod =>
                // start mode
                val prodConf = Configuration(ConfigFactory.load("prod.conf"))
                builder.loadConfig(prodConf ++ context.initialConfiguration).bindings(new ProdModule());
            case Dev =>
                // run mode
                val devConf = Configuration(ConfigFactory.load("dev.conf"))
                builder.loadConfig(devConf ++ context.initialConfiguration).bindings(new DevModule());
            case Test =>
                // test mode
                val testConf = Configuration(ConfigFactory.load("test.conf"))
                builder.loadConfig(testConf ++ context.initialConfiguration).bindings(new TestModule());
        }
    }
}
```

Java version:

```
public class CustomApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader {

    @Override
    public GuiceApplicationBuilder builder(ApplicationLoader.Context context) {
        final Environment environment = context.environment();
        GuiceApplicationBuilder builder = initialBuilder.in(environment);
        Configuration config = context.initialConfiguration();
        if (environment.isTest()) {
            config = merge("test.conf", config);
            builder = builder.bindings(new TestModule());
        } else if (environment.isDev()) {
            config = merge("dev.conf", config);
            builder = builder.bindings(new DevModule());
        } else if (environment.isProd()) {
            config = merge("prod.conf", config);
            builder = builder.bindings(new DevModule());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No such mode.");
        }
        return builder.in(environment).loadConfig(config);
    }

    private Configuration merge(String configName, Configuration currentConfig) {
        return new Configuration(currentConfig.getWrappedConfiguration().$plus$plus(new play.api.Configuration(ConfigFactory.load(configName))));
    }
}
```

Do not forget to include `play.application.loader = "modules.CustomApplicationLoader"` to your `application.conf`.

In lower versions of `Play` something similar can be achieved by using `GlobalSettings` class and overriding `onLoadConfig`. Mind `GlobalSettings` in `Play 2.4` is depracted.

If you don't like including `test.conf` and `test mocks` from `TestModule` to your production build, you can `filter` the files with [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Howto/defaultpaths.html#source-include-filter).

Comment: And add `play.application.loader = "modules.CustomApplicationLoader"` into `application.conf`?

Comment: Yup. Follow the link in the answer for more details.

Comment: I think the stackoverflow policy is to copy/paste things over because links can go dead.

Comment: Yeah true, however an answer doesnt looks neat with a link pasted. :-)

Comment: When I follow the approach above in Scala, I get a `ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors: 1) No implementation for play.api.Application was bound.`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Doesn't work in test mode for me. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/JnxK4MiQf74

Answer (score 3):

You can set a different config file using one of the 3 ways play gives to you:

> 1 - Using -Dconfig.resource
>
> It will search for an alternative configuration file in the
>   application classpath (you usually provide these alternative
>   configuration files into your application conf/ directory before
>   packaging). Play will look into conf/ so you don’t have to add conf/.
>
> $ /path/to/bin/ -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf
>
> 2 - Using -Dconfig.file
>
> You can also specify another local configuration file not packaged
>   into the application artifacts:
>
> $ /path/to/bin/ -Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/prod.conf
>
> 3 - Using -Dconfig.url
>
> You can also specify a configuration file to be loaded from any URL:
>
> $ /path/to/bin/
>   -Dconfig.url=http://conf.mycompany.com/conf/prod.conf

Checkout more on:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionConfiguration

Comment: Yes, I know how to specify configs, but I'm specifically looking for how to specify configuration options depending on `run`/`start`/`test`, e.g. `javaOptions in Run`

Answer (score 1):

This thing can be done by having loading config files based on the environment which can be supplied via `-Dmode=staging/dev/prod`, and for loading the files I override `onLoadConfig` of GlobalSettings in Global.java.

Java snippet-

```
 @Override
 public Configuration onLoadConfig(Configuration config, File file,ClassLoader classLoader) {
 Configuration updatedConfig = config;
 String mode = config.getString("mode");
 if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(mode)) {
   try {
     File modeFolder = FileUtils.getFile(file, "conf/" + mode);
     if (modeFolder.exists()) {
       play.api.Configuration modeConfig = config.getWrappedConfiguration();
       IOFileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.conf");
       Collection<File> fileList = FileUtils.listFiles(modeFolder, fileFilter, null);
       for (File confFile : fileList) {
         modeConfig = modeConfig
            .$plus$plus(new play.api.Configuration(ConfigFactory.parseFile(confFile)));

      }
       updatedConfig = new Configuration(modeConfig);
     }
   } catch (Exception e) {
     Logger.error("Exception while loading configuration for mode : " + mode, e);
   }
 } else {
   Logger.error("Please provide mode in which play application has to start (Ex. play -Dmode=<mode>) ");
 }
```

For each mode, create a folder(name same as environment) and keep environment specific config in that folder.