# How to run ScalaTest with Guice DI and Slick?

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, slick, play-slick

I don't know how to configure `GuiceApplicationBuilder` in such a way, that I am able to load controllers that require a `DatabaseConfigProvider` to be injected.

I'd like to specify an alternative *postgres* database for testing, or an in memory database (if that is possible).

**Code**

```
class   User
extends MySpecs
with    OneAppPerTest
{
    override def newAppForTest( testData: TestData ) = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
        // Somehow bind a database here, I guess?
        .build()

    "A test" should "test" in
    {
        val result = Application.instanceCache[api.controller.User]
            .apply( app )
            .list()( FakeRequest() )

        ...
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
[info] - should return an entity *** FAILED ***
[info]   com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:
[info] 
[info] 1) No implementation for play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider was bound.
[info]   while locating play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
[info]     for parameter 1 at api.controller.User.<init>(User.scala:22)
[info]   while locating api.controller.User
[info] 
[info] 1 error
[info]   at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1042)
[info]   at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
[info]   at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
[info]   at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:321)
[info]   at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:316)
[info]   at play.api.Application$$anonfun$instanceCache$1.apply(Application.scala:234)
[info]   at play.api.Application$$anonfun$instanceCache$1.apply(Application.scala:234)
[info]   at play.utils.InlineCache.fresh(InlineCache.scala:69)
[info]   at play.utils.InlineCache.apply(InlineCache.scala:55)
[info]   ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a configuration to your `GuiceApplicationBuilder()`, then everything should be handled automatically by play framework. Something like this should help:

```
val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
        .configure(
            Configuration.from(
                Map(
                    "slick.dbs.YOURDBNAME.driver" -> "slick.driver.H2Driver$",
                    "slick.dbs.YOURDBNAME.db.driver" -> "org.h2.Driver",
                    "slick.dbs.YOURDBNAME.db.url" -> "jdbc:h2:mem:",

                    "slick.dbs.default.driver" -> "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$",
                    "slick.dbs.default.db.driver" -> "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                )
            )
        )
        .in(Mode.Test)
        .build()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a little bit of setting up in this approach but the final result is fair. First of all start with implementing your own `GuiceApplicationLoader` by extending it. See my [answer how to implement it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787961/configuration-depending-on-launch-mode/30797238#30797238). Why your own application loader? You can specify different configs/modules per `Prod/Dev/Test` modes - as well as different data sources. Your main `application.conf` wouldn't have data source configured. Instead, you would move it to environment specific configurations which would be merged with main configuration by application loader anyway. Your `dev.conf` would look as follows:

```
slick.dbs {
  default {
    driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$",
    db {
      driver = "org.postgresql.Driver",
      url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dev",
      user = "postgres"
      password = "postgres"
    }
  }
}
```

And the trick now is to use **same** data source name, in this case `default`, for all other configurations (the database url, drivers,  credentials etc. would be different). With such setup, your `evolutions` will be applied to your test and dev database. Your `test.conf` could look as follows:

```
slick.dbs {
  default {
    // in memory configuration
  }
}
```

In your tests, use `WithApplicationLoader` with your custom application loader instead and thats it.

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ApplicationSpec extends Specification {

    "Application" should {

        "return text/html ok for home" in new WithApplicationLoader(new CustomApplicationLoader) {
          val home = route(FakeRequest(routes.ApplicationController.home())).get
          status(home) must equalTo(OK)
          contentType(home) must beSome.which(_ == "text/html")
        }

    }

}
```

Within the test itself, you have an access to `app: Application` value:

```
val service = app.injector.instanceOf(classOf[IService])
```

Comment: how do you decouple test code from prod code then? For instance what if I want to have some mock classes in `TestModule`? Since your `CustomApplicationLoader` will be in production code won't it be a problem?

Comment: `CustomApplicationLoader` will run in `Test` mode in tests with `test.conf` and `TestModule` installed.

Comment: I am aware of that, but you are using `new TestModule()` in your `CustomApplicationLoader` which means that all the classes that are used in `TestModule` have to be accessible from production code, a lot of people (including myself) don't like to mix test and prod code.

Comment: I inject my dependencies by trait (interface) and I have an abstract base module from all three modules extend where I bind shared implementations. so `CommonModule` contains shared implementations, `TestModule` test specific and `ProdModule` prod specific.

Comment: Yes but if `TestModule` contains all the test only classes and you do `new TestModule()` in `CustomApplicationLoader` which is in your `src` then you have to also put all the test only classes that are used by `TestModule` inside `src` and not `test` folders, right? There has to be a coupling between `test` and `src` folders then or am I missing something?

Comment: I see your point now, basically you do not like **shipping** prod code with test code, is it right?

Comment: yes exactly, I try to separate my prod and test code as much as possible unless there is a good reason not to (or there is no other way)

Comment: Nothing forbids you from implementing `TestApplicationLoader`, wiring up dependencies yourself and keeping all classes and files under `test` directory. `GuiceApplicationLoader` is designed for extension.

Comment: True but then I can just use `GuiceApplicationBuilder`, all those loaders seem like a bit of an overhead for such a simple thing

Comment: The point is to centralize test configuration and test dependencies.

Comment: yes but my point is, if we do split them into 2 loaders then do we really need it? Making a trait with `newAppForTest` and using `GuiceApplicationBuilder` will always save us a few lines of code and give the same result, won't it? That's what I'm looking for - a reason to actually implement `GuiceApplicationLoader`. It would be reasonable if we were to do it as in your other answer with all the modes in one place but as I pointed out above some might find that to be a bad practice.

Comment: If you are worried about test and prod source code getting mixed, just exclude it from packaging. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491505/how-to-exclude-resources-during-packaging-with-sbt-but-not-during-testing